# Imacro - Pause Loop after 5 time run

Tags: loops, macros, imacros, immediate-mode

I wanna add some condition in loop that once its completed run of 5 time then it move to Pause option instead of every time.Thankyou

```
VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE email.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 45
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=image.jpg WAIT=YES
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Request<SP>contact<SP>details
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/contact_league ATTR=NAME:first_name CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/contact_league ATTR=NAME:last_name CONTENT={{!COL3}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/contact_league ATTR=NAME:email CONTENT={{!COL4}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=HREF:*recaptcha* CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEPICTUREAS
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
URL GOTO=http://api.deathbycaptcha.com/decaptcher?function=picture2&amp;print_format=html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:username CONTENT=mylogin
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT=mypassword
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:pict CONTENT=C:\Users\datlik\Documents\iMacros\Downloads\image.jpg
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=TYPE:submit
WAIT SECONDS=9
TAG POS=6 TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
pause
TAB CLOSE
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/contact_league ATTR=ID:recaptcha_response_field CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
pause''
```

Comment: You have to use JavaScript scripting and if clause. There are tons of examples on stackoverflow.

Comment: Can anyone help me out with this, because i am not familiar with Java, Can anyone help me how to manage this script?

Comment: Here is a simple solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207747/imacros-if-else-javascript-simple